# compile errors happens in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

data02.in is numerical data in which one real number value is described in one line. From this numerical data, create a program that discovers the maximum and minimum values. The program to create is

1. It works even if the number of numbers stored in the file is
   changed.
2. Each time numerical data is read from a file, it is compared and updated with the maximum and minimum values.

It shall be. Create this according to the following procedure.

1. First, prepare three variables of double type that store the
   numerical value, maximum value, and minimum value to be read. The
   initial values ​​of the maximum value and the minimum value are set
   to the minimum value and the maximum value that can be taken by the
   numerical data, respectively. Since the given numerical data is
   known to be non-negative, the initial value of the maximum value is
   set to 0. The initial value of the minimum value is the maximum
   value of double type DBL_MAX. DBL_MAX is defined in the header file
   <float.h>, so you need to include it before you can use it. (DBL_MAX
   is a macro that represents the maximum value that can be represented
   by double type).
2. Read a number from a file. Compare this with the maximum value, and
   if it is larger, update the maximum value. The minimum value is also
   compared and updated in the same way.
3. Return to 2. and repeat the process until the next numerical value
   cannot be read.
4. Outputs the found maximum and minimum numbers up to the fourth
   decimal place to the file data02.out, and terminates the program.

data02.in

```
0.04352715661330464
0.5711499219614311
0.5510152700437206
0.4349183348106874
0.5655036481971432
0.778936411144494
0.9653850342847657
0.3212329719743001
0.14875984255792618
0.7334184832076945
0.3015893694560843
0.778596472495796
0.6062732756985176
0.8703907121064157
0.726552074397092
0.33992379312230137
0.1631129989837965
0.9676628599119076
0.585461667958953
0.8615281807925766
0.8007898389888695
0.9492303287750206
0.45691105334861526
0.11234397028174314
0.12211793272128402
0.5159930438804902
0.025879785403056355
0.19976268362579752
0.48253690657173065
0.7636664896336439
```

Error compile

```
    gcc prog02.c
prog02.c: In function ‘main’:
prog02.c:8:16: error: ‘MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    8 |     double min=MAX;
      |                ^~~
prog02.c:8:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
prog02.c:22:44: error: called object ‘max’ is not a function or function pointer
   22 |   fprintf(fpout,"max = %.3f, min = %.3f\n",max(n),min(n));
      |                                            ^~~
prog02.c:7:12: note: declared here
    7 |     double max=0;
      |            ^~~
prog02.c:22:51: error: called object ‘min’ is not a function or function pointer
   22 |   fprintf(fpout,"max = %.3f, min = %.3f\n",max(n),min(n));
      |                                                   ^~~
prog02.c:8:12: note: declared here
    8 |     double min=MAX;
```

source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(){
  FILE *fpin,*fpout;
  double n;
    double max=0;
    double min=MAX;
  
  fpin = fopen("rand.in","r");
  
  fpout = fopen("rand.out","w");

  while(fscanf(fpin,"%lf",&n) != EOF){
    
    if(n>max) max=n;
    
    if(n<min) min=n;
    
  }

  fprintf(fpout,"max = %.3f, min = %.3f\n",max(n),min(n));
    
  fclose(fpout);
  fclose(fpin);
}
```

Comment: Some suggestion for future questions: If you fail to compile your program, there is no need to show input data or expected output etc. Compilation errors are not related to any data as you do not get far enough to provide that data to the program. Also the description of your intention is mainly unnecessary. If the program is no valid C, it does not matter what you wanted to use the program for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `MAX` isn't declared anywhere. You could as well use `FOOBAR`, the result would be the same. BTW you were told to use `DBL_MAX`.
- `max(n),min(n)` : you're using max and min as functions just use `max` and `min`.

So you probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  FILE *fpin,*fpout;
  double n;
  double max=0;
  double min= DBL_MAX;
  
  fpin = fopen("rand.in","r");
  if (fpin == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  
  fpout = fopen("rand.out","w");
  if (fpout == NULL)
  {
    printf("Can't create file\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(fscanf(fpin,"%lf", &n) != EOF){    
    if (n > max) max = n;    
    if (n < min) min = n;
  }

  fprintf(fpout,"max = %.3f, min = %.3f\n", max, min);
    
  fclose(fpout);
  fclose(fpin);
}
```

Comment: Error diplays. warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   13 |     exit(1);
      |     ^~~~
prog02.c:13:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
prog02.c:3:1: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘exit’
    2 | #include <float.h>
  +++ |+#include <stdlib.h>
    3 | 
prog02.c:19:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
   19 |     exit(1);
      |     ^~~~
prog02.c:19:5: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘exit’

Comment: I edited the answer. BTW the error message tells you what to do. (`note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘exit’ `)

Comment: Yes. Error diplays. prog02.c: In function ‘main’:
prog02.c:15:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   15 |     exit(1);
      |     ^~~~
prog02.c:15:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
prog02.c:4:1: note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘exit’
    3 | #include <stddef.h>
  +++ |+#include <stdlib.h>
    4 | 
 warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
   22 |     exit(1);
      |     ^~~~
 note: include ‘<stdlib.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘exit’

Comment: My bad, it's `#include <stdlib.h>`. Answer updated. It should work now.